# Why JQuery dialog goes slightly outside the main window when in maximized mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When i open Jquery dialog in maximized mode using $(window).width() &  $(window).height() or  $(document).width() &  $(document).height(). It slightly goes out of main window. My Jquery code is:

```
function DisableBackGrd() {
        var dlg = $("#divCreateInqGeneral").dialog({ bgiframe: true,
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height(),
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            focus: function () { hideScrollBars(); },
            open: function () { hideScrollBars(); },
            beforeClose: function () { showScrollBars(); }
        });
        dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    }
```

Relevant HTML

```
<div id="divCreateInqGeneral" style="display: none">
    <uc1:CreateInqGeneral ID="Tab1UCCreateInqGeneral" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: what if you try width & height 100 % ?

Comment: How?  width: '100%',
            height: '100%' does not work. It throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something here:

```
var theDialog = $(".mydialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    width:'auto'
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Bind an event in window.resize like this:

```
$(window).resize(){
//Resize height/width of your dialog here
}
```